# my girlfriend is colombia and needs to pass through UK

Tags: usa, uk, transit-visas, ireland, colombian-citizens

basically, my girlfriend will need to pass through USA Orlando airport and the UK in Manchester airport to arrive at Dublin, will she need any kind of visa for both countries since she is Colombian?

Comment: Does she have a visa to enter Ireland? You can check UK transit visa requirements here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: no we still need to sort out the visas for both united states and ireland, do you have any links for the US one or the Irish one?

Comment: You must get the visa for her final destination (Ireland http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Apply%20for%20a%20visa) first, since that is her premise for the transit visa(s).

Comment: she is coming from Dublin to Belfast though, should that affect anything? sorry with all the questions and addons ^.^

Comment: If your final destination is Belfast, you should know that it is in the UK, not Ireland. She is not passing through the UK at all, she is going to the UK and passing through Ireland.

Comment: @ryan mcfaul Please edit your question to clarify the exact route, end destination, and whether the ticket will be booked as a single trip (one PNR). Also, I recommend you read this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e before applying for a UK visa

Answer (score 2):

She will certainly need a USA visa, as the Orlando Airport does not have a sterile transit zone. She needs a visa for Ireland. I hope one of the UK experts can answer better, but *my* reading of [this page](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa) is that she does not need a UK visa *if she has an Irish **biometric** visa*.

Comment: To deal with the apparent suggestion that the final destination is Belfast. Ryanair has multiple cheap flights per day from Manchester to Belfast. Unless there was an amazing deal to Dublin going through both Orlando and Manchester, your itinerary doesn't seem reasonable. I suggest looking again at the ticket. If you are in Belfast, then of course your girlfriend needs a UK Visitors Visa, and on a more sensible itinerary, no visa for Ireland at all.

Comment: While it's correct that Orlando has no sterile transit zone, it's more correct to observe that *no* US airport has one. Wherever a traveler first  lands in the US, the traveler must pass through US immigration and customs.